# What to use for synchronization of asynchronous requests and responses in C# in my task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have stream of requests. Each request is separate thread. Each thread is created by one function (`GetHistoryData(securityCode)`).

All requests wait responses that are obtained by another threads that are created by another function (`handleCallback(input)`).

And now I have stream of initial requests and final responses.

- Each response must be related with corresponding request
- Each response can be obtained by another order than order of requests.

For example, the application make requests:

- request1 for USD history data
- request2 for Apple history data
- request3 for Google history data

And receives responses

- response1 of USD history data
- response2 of Google history data
- response3 of Apple history data

Problem is the responses can come not in same order as requests. It leads that thread waiting respose recieve response of another thread when I began use this code for multithreding purposes with using of AutoResetEvent

How to synchronize it? What should I use for this case?

Maybe you know any patterns for this case?

I try to use different solutions like Monitor, AutoresetEvent etc but..

Parts of code are correct before I have used it for multithreading tasks. For multithreading tasks this code is not correct and I'm searching solution.

```
public List<candle> GetHistoryData(string seccode, boardsCode board = boardsCode.FUT, SecurityPeriods periodId = SecurityPeriods.M1, int candlesCount = 1)
{
    candle res = null;
    command com = command.CreateGetHistoryDataCommand(board, seccode, periodId, candlesCount);
    result sendResult = ConnectorSendCommand(com, typeof(command));
    if (sendResult.success == true)
    {
        _candlesLoaded.WaitOne();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(sendResult.message);
    }
    return _candles.candlesValue;
}

protected override void _handleData(String result)
{
    string nodeName = _getNodeName(result);
    switch (nodeName)
    {
        case "candles":
            var candles = (candles)XMLHelper.Deserialize(result, typeof(candles));
            _currentCandle = candles.candlesValue[0];
            _candles = candles;
            _candlesLoaded.Set();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your actual `GetHistoryData(securityCode)` function.

Comment: _"I have stream of requests. Each request is separate thread."_ - Show us your **actual code** where you spin-up threads and assign threads to process requests.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task)/[`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) classes? Have you considered using them instead of threads?

Comment: yes, I use Task classes

Comment: @MaksimRudnev Nowhere in your posted code are you doing anything with `Thread` or `Task`.

Comment: `_candlesLoaded.WaitOne();` <-- _oooooh boy_ - your code is going to deadlock so hard one day.

Comment: _"yes, I use Task classes"_ not in code shown. Either that's not your real code or you in fact don't use `Task`. Either way, we cannot help based on the information given. Please improve your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `result sendResult = ConnectorSendCommand(com, typeof(command));` .... is this some sort of attempt of a [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) ?

Comment: The `GetHistoryData` method has side-effects. Please show a [mcve] otherwise we can't help you. Good questions have good answers within minutes here. Your question isn't good.

Comment: @Dai Task is created 2 levels above this function. This function is called within cycle inside Task. And there are array of Tasks which call this function. It's difficult to show in post. I will try to make github repository with example

Comment: @MaksimRudnev Your project sounds like it needs significant refactoring. I don't think we can really help you.

Comment: @MaksimRudnev - If it is difficult for you to show your problem then it is probably difficult for us to answer. A [mcve] is needed.

Answer (score -1):

The code show seems to miss important parts and the bits shown have elements that are not used so it's not easy to provide a precise answer, but generally speaking there are two simple mechanisms to do multiple things ~at the same time in C# that handle 'synchronisation':

1. `Task.WhenAny`, for examples see [Process asynchronous tasks as they complete (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete);
2. `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.ForEachAsync`; for an example see [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)